# Access WSO2 Data Services Service via WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

I have created a service (Products) which accepts a ProductID value and returns data.  I have SOAP and HTTP requests and responses for this service.  I can access this by doing something like h**p://localhost:9763/services/Products.HTTPEndpoint/ProductID/123456 to return data.

How can I do the same thing but go through the ESB?  I've tried to set up a simple pass through proxy, but when I use the "TryIt" I only get "mediate" as a option.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up being able to do this:

WSO2 Data Services Server service:

```
http://localhost:9763/services/Products
```

WSO2 ESB Endpoint:

```
Name: epProducts
Address: http://localhost:9763/services/Products.HTTPEndpoint
Format: GET
```

WSO2 ESB Proxy Service:

```
Service Name: ProductsProxy
Publishing WSDL: None
Define In Sequence:  None
Define Endpoint:  epProducts
Define Out Sequence: None
Define Fault Sequence: None
```

Send a GET request to:

```
http://localhost:9763/services/Products.HTTPEndpoint/ProductID/123456
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use an appropriate WDSDL as the publish WSDL of the proxy service to 'tryit' the proxy service.
So what you can do is, get the WSDL of the actual data service and use that as the publish wsdl of the proxy. Then you can use tryit to invoke the DS.

Comment: Thanks Kasun. I figured out a different way to do it (posting my solution as well).