# Error while implementing Rest API in wso2esb

Tags: rest, curl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.1.0.I have created restful service in wso2dss with following configuration :

```
<query id="selectall" useConfig="default">
      <sql>select userid,username,password from usertable</sql>
      <result element="Entries" rowName="Entry">
         <element column="userid" name="userid" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="username" name="username" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="password" name="password" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
   </query>

  <resource method="GET" path="user1">
      <call-query href="selectall"/>
   </resource>
```

It's working fine in dss with below curl command

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://192.168.1.23:9764/services/A_resttest.HTTPEndpoint/user1
```

Now i wish to use this service in wso2esb.How can i access this in esb.For this i have created an endpoint :

```
Name: resttestendp
Address: http://192.168.1.23:9764/services/A_resttest.HTTPEndpoint
Format: GET
```

and my esb configuration is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="RESTtest"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
      <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="resttestendp"/>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

curl using to access it is:

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://youtility-desktop:8282/services/RESTtest.HTTPEndpoint/user1
```

but it showing error :

```
ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Where should i make changes or i have to implement rest api concept? let me know..
I referred : [Access WSO2 Data Services Service via WSO2 ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179661/access-wso2-data-services-service-via-wso2-esb)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create API in ESB if you need to implement REST API inside ESB. Please use below links for more help.

A Sample:
https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+800%3A+Introduction+to+REST+API

More help on verifying the usage

[WSO2 ESB - REST API - Response Does Not Come](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512677/wso2-esb-rest-api-response-does-not-come)

In General:

https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Getting+Started+with+REST+APIs

Comment: hi jayalalk..Thanks for reply..I have tried  https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+800%3A+Introduction+to+REST+API  But it also showing same error i.e NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException in server side

Comment: First of all, make sure sample given by the sample link is working fine. Take a new copy of ESB to new location and start ESB with command. "bin>wso2esb-samples.sh -sn 800"  , then try accessing API using curl. If this works then you know how to make API